# Authentication From a ASP.NET WebApi Using App+User Context for Sharepoint

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

Scenario :
1.  Spfx Webpart (On Sharepoint sitecollection) calls a WEBApi protected by Azure AD.
    a.  Obtain Access Token (Implicit) from an Enterprise App (App registration in Azure AD) representing the WEB Api
    b.  Attach the access token as a header in the Fetch Request to the Web Api UpdateList method (Updates a list in a Sharepoint site collection)
2.  WEBApi is making CSOM REST Calls using App Only Context generated using a Sharepoint Add-in’s Client ID and Secret (created through AppRegNew.aspx on the SiteCollection level)
    a.  The Sharepoint Add-in has SiteCollection level permissions granted by Admin
    b.  The WebApi is adding an item to a list in the same SiteCollection as the add-in using CSOM.
    c.  The “Created By” and “Modified By” list properties reflects the Application which did the update because it is using the app only ClientContext

Ask:       A way to implement app + user Authorization. The End Result should be that the “Created By” and “Modified By” fields should have the User Names rather than App Names

Answer (score 0):

You are using App-Only which means that Created By and Modified By will always be an Add-In name. You would have to use App+User permissions to have the Created By and Modified By set to real user instead an Add-In name.

Uncheck the App-Only checkbox in application manifest.